# Duplicate TCP acknowledgements and force retransmissions

Tags: tcp

How many duplicate Transmission Control Protocol acknowledgements does it take to force a retransmission?

Comment: Have you read [RFC 793](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)? If it's not in there, or a subsequent revision, then it is implementation-specific.

Comment: None. The question doesn't make sense. One ACK for a prior segment will cause retransmisstion of the current segment. No duplicates involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about [TCP Fast Retransmit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion-avoidance_algorithm#Fast_transmit).

The latest spec for it looks like [RFC 5681](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681) and specifically [section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681#section-3.2). It looks like the 3rd duplicate ACK (4th ACK total) for the same sequence # is what should trigger the resending of data.